# Rubber permeability of hydrogen to air

Tags: physical-chemistry

I am currently studying permeation of rubber film in a university practice group.
The problem is to evaluate the permeation of hydrogen gas filled in a meteorological balloon placed in the air, but how to build a mathematical model?
In particular, it is about how the penetration phenomenon is when the rubber balloon goes up and down.

The statement is as following: A weather balloon contains hydrogen gas floats in air with its buoyancy. As balloon flies higher pressure in balloon decreases and at the same time volume of balloon increases. But because of partial pressure difference between the inside balloon and the outside balloon hydrogen permeates through rubber membrane of balloon to outside air.

How to evaluate permeation model of this phenomenon?
And also when balloon descent from high altitude to ground how this model is made?

Comment: When the balloon descends, it rather performs a free fall after its rapture, which jhappens when it has the diameter >= 3m, typically at 25-30 km. So it is a question rather for aerodynamics than gas diffusion. (  meteorology background during my enlisted military service at air force airfield in 1989-1990.

Comment: Thanks for Poutnik, and my problem is on study not real project. And I mean if hydrogen filled balloon ,which its buoyancy is not enough for its payload weight,  descent, how to model hydrogen permeation? Sorry for not enough explation

Comment: Every useful word saved in the initial question formulation is paid later by several words posted by responders and the question poster during clarification. :-)

Comment: When expanding to the twice as big diameter, the rubber becomes 4 times thinner with  bigger pores to flow through and faster diffusion through rubber itself. Not easy to simulate.

Comment: High permeability to hydrogen is why helium is generally used.

Comment: @blacksmith37, Do radiosondes last long enough for permeability to matter? As Poutnik states, they reach a maximum altitude and achieve rapture (beamed down?) so as not to be an aviation hazard. Helium is preferred, I think, for *safety*.

Comment: Depends on "rubber film" definition. Cheap, thin balloons lose most of the hydrogen in a day.

Comment: @blacksmith37 In meteorology, hydrogen is ( or at least was ) used for baloons, as in the supposed timeframe, permeability is not an issue. You would spend the whole He cylinder in a week or so  and helium is not exactly cheap. See also that [wikipedia.org: Weather_balloon#Materials_and_equipment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_balloon#Materials_and_equipment) says *The balloon is usually filled with hydrogen due to lower cost, though helium can also be used.*